# PDFKit Paths with fill, stroke and opacity

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I've been using PDFKit with NodeJS to generate PDFs for an application we are developing and I'm not being able to set stroke opacity and fill opacity to a path.

This is an image how it should look like:
[image: Image from the builder]

This is how it's being displayed in the PDF: (Ignore the slightly greys in a few areas, it's watermarks)
[image: PDF Image]

The opacity value should be 0.6 in both. This is how I'm trying to apply the fill stroke and opacity:

```
pdfDocument.path(pathString);
pdfDocument.lineCap('butt');
pdfDocument.lineJoin('miter');
pdfDocument.lineWidth(strokeWidth);

pdfDocument.fillOpacity(opacity);
pdfDocument.strokeOpacity(opacity);

pdfDocument.fillAndStroke(fillColor, strokeColor, fillRule);

pdfDocument.stroke();
```

I'm not getting why is not applying opacity to stroke and fill. I already tried using only opacity function and move both sets of the opacity around but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging the library and found this issue from 2014

[Opacity #259](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/259)

Turns out that we need to set the `fillColor` with opacity and `strokeColor` with opacity before setting `fillAndStroke`.

```
pdfDocument.path(pathString);
pdfDocument.lineCap('butt');
pdfDocument.lineJoin('miter');
pdfDocument.lineWidth(strokeWidth);

// HERE IS THE TRICK.
pdfDocument.fillColor(fillColor, opacity);
pdfDocument.strokeColor(strokeColor, opacity);

pdfDocument.fillAndStroke(fillColor, strokeColor, fillRule);

pdfDocument.stroke();
```